# JPQL join tables doubles column names

Tags: join, double, eclipselink, jpql, criteria-api

I have multiple tables in a join and every table has a column ID. So in the resultig join there are a lot of ID columns. How I can access a specific ID column with the criteria API?

```
ParameterExpression<A> idParam = criteriaBuilder.parameter(A.class, PARAM_NAME);
Subquery<B> sq = query.subquery(B.class);
Root<B> root = sq.from(B.class);
Join<C, D> joinTogether = root.join("memberX").join("memberY");
sq.select(root);
sq.where(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(joinTogether.get("id"), idParam), criteriaBuilder.equal(parentQuery.get("id"), root.get("id"))));
```

The problem is, that in the resulting SQL contains

```
SELECT 1 FROM E t6, B t5, C t4, D t3 WHERE ((( = paramName) AND (t0.ID = t5.ID)) AND (((t6.memberZ = t5.ID) AND (t4.ID = t6.memberX)) AND (t3.ID = t4.memberY))))
```

The table E (t6) is an additional join table between table B and C, t0 is the reference to the parent query. Instead t3.id = :paramName EclipseLink creates nothing just before the first equal-sign (paramName is the content of the constant PARAM_NAME). My idea is, that the "id" column could reference all tables and EclipseLink can not decide, which table I mean.

How I can change that?

Thank you
André

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Is EclipseLink generating invalid SQL queries?

Comment: I'm not whether it is Eclipselink or my code. EclipseLink creates the SQL statement, but it contains a wrong equals-part. I think, I have to modify my code, but I don't know how. In the meantime I have used the meta model and I have changed joinTogether.get("id") to joinTogether.get(D_.id), but it doesn't change the resulting SQL.

Comment: If Eclipselink is generating that SQL I think you might have found a bug.

Comment: My guess is that the generated query is missing something because it's a subquery. Try printing the final query instead.